# Jboss can't deploy ear container with spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss, spring-security

I'm working on project with one EJB and one WAR packed as EAR. `mvn install` runs OK, but JBoss EAP 6.3 can't deploy it.

pom.xml (ear)

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Modules -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.XXX.yyy</groupId>
        <artifactId>yyy-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.XXX.yyy</groupId>
        <artifactId>yyy-ws</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>6</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <modules>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>eu.XXX.yyy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>yyy-ejb</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>yyy-ejb.jar</bundleFileName>
                    </ejbModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>eu.XXX.yyy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>yyy-ws</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>yyy-ws.war</bundleFileName>
                        <contextRoot>/yyy</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

pom.xml (war)

```
...
<endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
<spring.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
...
<dependencies>
    <!-- EJB module -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.XXX.yyy</groupId>
        <artifactId>yyy-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependecies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

pom.xml (ejb)

```
...
<endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
<spring.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
...
<dependecies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependecies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The project has two spring contexts. One located in EJB module, another one in WAR module.

In context located in WAR, there is a line `<import resource="classpath*:ejbContext.xml" />`. And in web.xml there is

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:securityContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

where securityContex.xml is located in WAR.

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/yyy]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 103) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:ejbContext.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [securityContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [vfs:/content/yyy-ear-0.1.ear/yyy-ejb.jar/ejbContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:248) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:199) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [vfs:/content/yyy-ear-0.1.ear/yyy-ejb.jar/ejbContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:242) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:128) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1419) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
... 35 more
```

I think that poms are not configured correctly, but I don't know how to fix it. Any Ideas?

Comment: You probably have jars in your EAR/lib direcotry and in your WEB-INF/lib directory. Leading to loadnig of classes in different class loaders making a `NamespaceHandler` no `NamespaceHandler`. Class identity is based on classname an dthe classloader it resides in. The same class loaded in different classloaders aren't the same, hence a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @M.Deinum. I had to exclude a lot of libraries from spring libraries in WAR module, but it works now.

Comment: You don't have to exclude them, making them `<scope>provided</scope>` should do the trick.